# Prolog: assign the tail of a list to a variable?

Tags: list, prolog

I have some prolog code below, which takes a list of integers, and returns me the Max element of said list. My issue is that I'm not quite sure how the`List = [H|_]` portion of the code works.

I understand that `H` gets assigned the head value of the list, but the variable List below is what? How does prologue know to take the tail and assign it to List when given the following snippet of code `List = [H|_]`

To me `List` could either be `H` or it could be `_` (the tail)... but logically it has to be `_` (the tail) or the function below would not work.

```
max(List,Max)  :- 
         List  =  [H|_], 
         accMax(List,H,Max).
```

Example of code : http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse21

Comment: Your statement, *To me `List` could either be `H` or it could be `_` (the tail).*  doesn't make sense. The `|` symbol in prolog is NOT a logical OR. It delimits the head versus the tail. `List = [H|_]` is simply a way of unifying the first element of `List` with `H`. Have you looked at the Prolog documentation?

Comment: @lurker, yes I'm currently going through the documentation, I understand that its not a logical OR. I should of rather explained that, I don't see how this snippet if code works.  

If you unify List with H, then you get accMax(H,H,Max). Which would mean that the max element of a list is always its first element, which is clearly wrong.

This part does not make sense to me, how do you get the max element if accMax only looks at the first element of a list.

I'm very confused with this snippet of code, which is why I'm here.

Comment: "take the tail and assign it to List" is wrong. `List` is the whole thing, `H` is the head and the tail has no name (`_`). I'm not sure why `accMax/3` takes the whole list as parameter one rather than just the tail.

Comment: @cicero866 *If you unify List with H...* You are NOT unifying `List` with `H`. `List` is being unified with the list form `[H|_]` which is a list with first element (head) of `H` and rest-of-list (tail) of `_`. Your statement, *To me List could either be `H` or it could be `_` (the tail).* doesn't make any sense given the code, unless you were thinking `|` somehow meant OR. The predicate could also be written like this: `max([H|T], Max) :- accMax([H|T], H, Max).`, which in my opinion would be clearer but it means the same thing.

Comment: I see, I must of misunderstood the `[H|T]` syntax. I thought that as soon as you saw the | delimiting symbol, that the head was automatically removed from the tail. And I was trying to figure out which the `List` was assigned. 

I also think that `accMax/3` taking the entire list is redundant. Do you know of an example which would only pass the tail. Would this work?

`max([H|T],Max)  :- 
         List  =  T, 
         accMax(List,H,Max).`

Comment: Nope. `[H|T]` doesn't remove anything. It is simply a representation for a list. And I agree that passing the entire list to `accMax` is probably redundant. I would bet you might be able to call `accMax(T, H, Max)` depending upon how `accMax/3` is written.

Comment: @lurker thank you. I understand the list representation better now. My use of the English language is suboptimal at best, when I said : To me `List` could either be `H` or it could be `_` (the tail), I was assuming that `[H|T]` forced List to unify with either `H` or `T` not the entire `[H|T]`. It was an error due to misunderstanding what `[H|T]` really meant. As such, I thought `List` took the value of `H` or `T` and I could not figure out which. Is it necessary to define `List = [H|T]` in the example above? If I said `max([1,2,3],Max).`would list not already be unified with `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: @cicero866 if  you call `max([1,2,3], Max)` then, yes, `List` unifies with `[1,2,3]`, but then how do you get the 1 to pas to `accMax(..., 1, Max)`? So the most expedient way is with `max([H|T],Max) :- accMax(T, H, Max).` The use of `List` in your `List = T, accMax(List, H, Max)` is ok but unnecessary.